# Is there a way of making a flutter webview use android camera for file upload? How to open file picker in webview_flutter flutter?

Tags: php, android, flutter, file-upload, webview

I have a flutter web application with a `webview` that loads my PHP project from a server. In my PHP project, I have a registration form that requires a user to capture photos using the camera then upload it to the MySQL DB. The problem is that when I click the upload file button to use the camera it does nothing. But in the browser, the file chooser is working but on my android from the `webview` it's not doing anything.

I tried this it's not working as well.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
Image 1 <span style="color:red">*</span><input type="file" name="img1" accept"image/*" capture="camera"  required>
</div>
```

Here are my imports too.

```
import 'package:car_renting_app/Animations/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:car_renting_app/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:car_renting_app/popup.dart';
import 'package:car_renting_app/ui/adminwebview.dart';
import 'package:car_renting_app/widgets/animated_botton_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
```

Here is my pubsec.yaml

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
webview_flutter:
simple_animations: ^1.1.3
page_transition: ^1.1.4
carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
url_launcher: ^5.1.1
sliding_up_panel: ^0.3.4
font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
connectivity:
uni_links:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an alternative solution using "webview_flutter" : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27924#issuecomment-647197754

Have to edit "FlutterWebView.java" and "AndroidManifest".

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of using `file picker` from `webview_flutter 4.0.2` on Android, iOS doesn't require any special changes. In the initState of your widget, add the following code

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidController = controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController;
      await androidController.setOnShowFileSelector(_androidFilePicker);
    }
```

The `_androidFilePicker` contains [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to pick files. With this code, if some presses on upload button on the HTML page, file picker opens on Android. You can check this [blog post](https://theprogrammingway.com/flutter-file-upload-using-webview-on-android/) if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

@Bruno's link answer did not work for me.
So I found many solutions and used them together and finally it worked for me.
`webview_flutter: ^2.0.8` (this solution should work with lower version too)

***Prerequisite** :- Permission handling should be implemented before implementing this solution camera and storage permissions*

1. Go to External libraries of your flutter
2. Navigate to webview_flutter plugin project folder
3. Navigate to android folder
4. Go to src>main
5. Open manifest file , it should be empty with just package name in it , then copy paste this

   ```
    <provider
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.GenericFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.generic.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            />
    </provider>

    </application>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos" />
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.docs" />
        <package android:name="com.google.android.documentsui" />
    </queries>
   ```
6. Create res directory if not there under main folder
7. Create values directory then create strings.xml in it: copy and paste this

```
<resources>
    <string name="webview_file_chooser_title">Choose a file</string>
    <string name="webview_image_chooser_title">Choose an image</string>
    <string name="webview_video_chooser_title">Choose a video</string>
</resources>
```

8. Create xml folder then create provider_paths.xml in it , copy and paste this

   ```
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="safetyapp_images" path="images" />
    </paths>
   ```
9. Go to main>java>io>flutter>plugins>webviewflutter
10. Create java class with name Constants.java and copy this

package io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter;

```
    public class Constants {
        static final String ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_FINISHED =
                "action_request_camera_permission_denied";
        static final String ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED = "action_file_chooser_completed";
    
        static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "extra_title";
        static final String EXTRA_ACCEPT_TYPES = "extra_types";
        static final String EXTRA_SHOW_VIDEO_OPTION = "extra_show_video_option";
        static final String EXTRA_SHOW_IMAGE_OPTION = "extra_show_image_option";
        static final String EXTRA_FILE_URIS = "extra_file_uris";
        static final String EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FILES = "extra_allow_multiple_files";
    
    
        static final String WEBVIEW_STORAGE_DIRECTORY = "images";
    }
```

11. Create FileChooserActivity.java and copy this

    package io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter;

    ```
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_ACCEPT_TYPES;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FILES;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_FILE_URIS;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_SHOW_IMAGE_OPTION;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_SHOW_VIDEO_OPTION;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_TITLE;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.WEBVIEW_STORAGE_DIRECTORY;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
    import android.util.Log;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class FileChooserActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE = 12322;
    private static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");

    // List of Uris that point to files where there MIGHT be the output of the capture. At most one of these can be valid
    private final ArrayList<Uri> potentialCaptureOutputUris = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showFileChooser(
                getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_IMAGE_OPTION, false),
                getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_VIDEO_OPTION, false));
    }

    private void showFileChooser(boolean showImageIntent, boolean showVideoIntent) {
        Intent getContentIntent = createGetContentIntent();
        Intent captureImageIntent =
                showImageIntent ? createCaptureIntent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, "jpg") : null;
        Intent captureVideoIntent =
                showVideoIntent ? createCaptureIntent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE, "mp4") : null;

        if (getContentIntent == null && captureImageIntent == null && captureVideoIntent == null) {
            // cannot open anything: cancel file chooser
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED));
            finish();
        } else {
            ArrayList<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (getContentIntent != null) {
                intentList.add(getContentIntent);
            }

            if (captureImageIntent != null) {
                intentList.add(captureImageIntent);
            }
            if (captureVideoIntent != null) {
                intentList.add(captureVideoIntent);
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, intentList.get(0));
            intentList.remove(0);
            if (intentList.size() > 0) {
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Intent[0]));
            }

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        Intent filesIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FILES, false)) {
            filesIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }

        String[] acceptTypes = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPT_TYPES);

        if (acceptTypes.length == 0 || (acceptTypes.length == 1 && acceptTypes[0].length() == 0)) {
            // empty array or only 1 empty string? -> accept all types
            filesIntent.setType("*/*");
        } else if (acceptTypes.length == 1) {
            filesIntent.setType(acceptTypes[0]);
        } else {
            // acceptTypes.length > 1
            filesIntent.setType("*/*");
            filesIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, acceptTypes);
        }

        return (filesIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) ? filesIntent : null;
    }

    private Intent createCaptureIntent(String type, String fileFormat) {
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(type);
        if (captureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create the File where the output should go
        Uri captureOutputUri = getTempUri(fileFormat);
        potentialCaptureOutputUris.add(captureOutputUri);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, captureOutputUri);

        return captureIntent;
    }
    private File getStorageDirectory() {
        File imageDirectory = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), WEBVIEW_STORAGE_DIRECTORY);
        if (!imageDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            imageDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        return imageDirectory;
    }


    private Uri getTempUri(String format) {
        String fileName = "CAPTURE-" + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()) + "." + format;
        File file = new File(getStorageDirectory(), fileName);
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".generic.provider", file);
    }

    private String getFileNameFromUri(Uri uri) {
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        assert returnCursor != null;
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
        returnCursor.close();
        return name;
    }

    private Uri copyToLocalUri(Uri uri) {
        File destination = new File(getStorageDirectory(), getFileNameFromUri(uri));

        try (InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
             OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".generic.provider", destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "Unable to copy selected image", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Intent fileChooserFinishedIntent = new Intent(ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null && (data.getDataString() != null || data.getClipData() != null)) {
                    if (data.getDataString() != null) {
                        // single result from file browser OR video from camera
                        Uri localUri = copyToLocalUri(data.getData());
                        if (localUri != null) {
                            fileChooserFinishedIntent.putExtra(
                                    EXTRA_FILE_URIS, new String[] {localUri.toString()});
                        }
                    } else if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        // multiple results from file browser
                        int uriCount = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                        String[] uriStrings = new String[uriCount];

                        for (int i = 0; i < uriCount; i++) {
                            Uri localUri = copyToLocalUri(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());
                            if (localUri != null) {
                                uriStrings[i] = localUri.toString();
                            }
                        }
                        fileChooserFinishedIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_FILE_URIS, uriStrings);
                    }
                } else {
                    // image result from camera (videos from the camera are handled above, but this if-branch could handle them too if this varies from device to device)
                    for (Uri captureOutputUri : potentialCaptureOutputUris) {
                        try {
                            // just opening an input stream (and closing immediately) to test if the Uri points to a valid file
                            // if it's not a real file, the below catch-clause gets executed and we continue with the next Uri in the loop.
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(captureOutputUri).close();
                            fileChooserFinishedIntent.putExtra(
                                    EXTRA_FILE_URIS, new String[] {captureOutputUri.toString()});
                            // leave the loop, as only one of the potentialCaptureOutputUris is valid and we just found it
                            break;
                        } catch (IOException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sendBroadcast(fileChooserFinishedIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
       }
     }
    ```
12. Create this class FileChooserLauncher.java and copy this

    package io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter;

    ```
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_FINISHED;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_ACCEPT_TYPES;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FILES;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_FILE_URIS;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_SHOW_IMAGE_OPTION;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_SHOW_VIDEO_OPTION;
    import static io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.Constants.EXTRA_TITLE;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

    public class FileChooserLauncher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;
    private String title;
    private boolean allowMultipleFiles;
    private boolean videoAcceptable;
    private boolean imageAcceptable;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback;
    private String[] acceptTypes;

    public FileChooserLauncher(
            Context context,
            boolean allowMultipleFiles,
            ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            String[] acceptTypes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allowMultipleFiles = allowMultipleFiles;
        this.filePathCallback = filePathCallback;
        this.acceptTypes = acceptTypes;

        if (acceptTypes.length == 0 || (acceptTypes.length == 1 && acceptTypes[0].length() == 0)) {
            // acceptTypes empty -> accept anything
            imageAcceptable = true;
            videoAcceptable = true;
        } else {
            for (String acceptType : acceptTypes) {
                if (acceptType.startsWith("image/")) {
                    imageAcceptable = true;
                } else if (acceptType.startsWith("video/")) {
                    videoAcceptable = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (imageAcceptable && !videoAcceptable) {
            title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.webview_image_chooser_title);
        } else if (videoAcceptable && !imageAcceptable) {
            title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.webview_video_chooser_title);
        } else {
            title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.webview_file_chooser_title);
        }
    }

    private boolean canCameraProduceAcceptableType() {
        return imageAcceptable || videoAcceptable;
    }

    private boolean hasCameraPermission() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!canCameraProduceAcceptableType() || hasCameraPermission()) {
            showFileChooser();
        } else {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_FINISHED);
            context.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RequestCameraPermissionActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED);
        context.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FileChooserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPT_TYPES, acceptTypes);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_IMAGE_OPTION, imageAcceptable && hasCameraPermission());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_VIDEO_OPTION, videoAcceptable && hasCameraPermission());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FILES, allowMultipleFiles);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_FINISHED)) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            showFileChooser();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FILE_CHOOSER_FINISHED)) {
            String[] uriStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_FILE_URIS);
            Uri[] result = null;

            if (uriStrings != null) {
                int uriStringCount = uriStrings.length;
                result = new Uri[uriStringCount];

                for (int i = 0; i < uriStringCount; i++) {
                    result[i] = Uri.parse(uriStrings[i]);
                }
            }

            filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            filePathCallback = null;
        }
      }
     }
    ```
13. There should a class called `FlutterWebView.java`
    Just copy this overriden method and paste inside it.

    ```
    @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(
            WebView webView,
            ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
      // info as of 2021-03-08:
      // don't use fileChooserParams.getTitle() as it is (always? on                Mi 9T Pro Android 10 at least) null
      // don't use fileChooserParams.isCaptureEnabled() as it is (always? on Mi 9T Pro Android 10 at least) false, even when the file upload allows images or any file
      final Context context = webView.getContext();
      final boolean allowMultipleFiles = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
              && fileChooserParams.getMode() == FileChooserParams.MODE_OPEN_MULTIPLE;
      final String[] acceptTypes = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
              ? fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes() : new String[0];
      new FileChooserLauncher(context, allowMultipleFiles, filePathCallback, acceptTypes)
              .start();
      return true;
    } }
    ```
14. Create a class `RequestCameraPermissionActivity.java` and paste this code there

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

```
    public class RequestCameraPermissionActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 12321;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_FINISHED));
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this will work in iOS build?

Comment: No, its for android only

Answer (score 0):

This is a PR that add `onShowFileChooser`

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3225

Maybe the next version will support this feature on Android.